# How to animate container view x & y position in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, jquery-animate, container-view

I want to be able to animate a container view from left to right. I'm planning on using a container as a menu that slides in from the left side of the screen when called. Is there a good example for this?

I found this [UIView example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial), would this apply for what I need?

Comment: Yes, that example would work.

Comment: yeah. that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by both Putz1103 and Rakesh the [listed link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial) works for animating a container view.